# How to deploy a java server application?

Tags: java, heroku, deployment

I have a school assignment to deploy the backend of our java app(it is not a web app). The teacher keeps asking me to deploy it on heroku or aws or someting else. I can't understand how can I do that for a simple java server app. I tried a lot of things, especially for heroku, one of them is building a spring boot app but it didn't work.
This is the code:

```
import java.net.*;
public class Server {
    public static void main(String arg[]){
        try {
            ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(3000);
            Socket s = server.accept();

            System.out.println("Connected");
        }catch(Exception e){}
    }
}
```

What can I do?

Comment: Is this your entire code or just an example? Deploying means you "install" it in the environment you need to deploy the application to. That would normally involve uploading the application to that environment and registering it there. I don't know Heroku well but in AWS there would be multiple ways, e.g. using containers (Docker or Kunernetes), creating an EC2 and running the jar there, uploading it to Beanstalk (Heroku seems similar to this) etc. - you might want to ask your teacher or peers for help if you don't know what do choose - you should at least have some requirements.

Comment: Since you got the task to deploy the application, didn't you cover servers, "serverless" etc. yet? Don't you have any material your teacher shared with you on how to do that? If not, have a look at available documentation - I feel that explaining all the steps here is way of of scope for SO.

Comment: Yes, this is the entire code for now, I just have a client which connects to the server. The thing is that I kept asking the teacher but I still can't understand how can I do that, and none of my peers understood. He kept saying that I should figure it out but the deadline is pretty close

Comment: You could start using this: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-java